# is a php executed in loop?

Tags: php, loops

I need to delete filename.html if existing, create a new filename.html and display it, but i have the following problem.
When a new filename.html is created, it is immediately killed, like the php is starting over.
Is there a way to execute it once?
This is my php.

```
<?php

  $filename = 'filename.html';

  if (file_exists($filename)) {       // if filename.html exist i delete it
     unlink($filename);
  }

  do {
    if (file_exists($filename)) {    // waiting for a new filename.html (generated by another process)
         include ($filename);        // i will show it when ready
         break;
    }
  } while(true);

?>
```

I tried also this workaround to execute the deletion only in the beginning, but it doesn't work:

```
if( !defined('ALREADYEXECUTED') ){       
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
     unlink($filename);
  }
}
define('ALREADYEXECUTED', TRUE);
```

Comment: How long does it take to generate the file? If it takes longer than your `max_execution_time` setting, your script will be killed.

Comment: You also want to flush stat-cache every now and then plus maybe add a short wait time before the next check. Note: Don't do too many file operations if the script is run by visitors, or your server can become unresponsive due to excessive  file I/O

Answer (score 0):

You are using an infinite loop in your code and this is not best practice for what you will to do!

You can use `header("Refresh:1")` to refresh your page to check the file existence every second. This can save your resource and also do what you want.

```
<?php
header("Refresh:2");
$filename = 'filename.html';

if (file_exists($filename)) { // if filename.html exist i delete it
    unlink($filename);
}

if (file_exists($filename)) { // waiting for a new filename.html (generated by another process)
    include ($filename); // i will show it when ready
}

?>
```

Be careful to delete `header("Refresh:2")` after including new file or use a condition to avoid that after include.

Answer (score 0):

the test with header("Refresh:2") didn't work for me, but it helped me to find a solution (surely there are better ones):

I had to split the php in 2:

the first:

```
<?php

  $filename = 'filename.html';

  if (file_exists($filename)) {       // if filename.html exist i delete it
     unlink($filename);
  }

  header('Location:secondfile.php');
}
```

and the second file is like this:

```
  <?php
    
      $filename = 'filename.html';
    
      do {
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
          usleep( 100000 );
          include ($filename);
          break;
        }
      } while(true);

  ?>
```

To answer to some questions:
The $filename is created in few milliseconds.
The file created, that was deleted immediately before, in this case is not deleted anymore.
I'm not expert of php, if there is a better solution to do it in one file i would be glad to learn.

Answer (score -1):

Simply get rid of the do while loop, thats whats causing your infinite loop. What purpose is that in there for originally?

Comment: i cannot remove the do while, as the new file is created after a variable time from few ms to 2sec, depending on what the server is doing